# using javascript modules with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a old angularjs app (using 1.2) and I'm trying to tidy my code into javascript modules, however I cannot figure out how to set the controller to be a function in the module, i.e. I want to move from:

```
  <script>
    function Controller($scope){
      // do stuff
    }
  </script>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="Controller"></div>
```

to something a bit more like

```
  <script type="module">
    export function Controller($scope){
      // do stuff
    }
  </script>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="Controller"></div>
```

but cannot work out how, I don't particularly need the top level function to be within a module but I would like to call functions from modules within it, which as far as I can tell means it also has to be a module, is there a way to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that exporting from a JavaScript module does not automatically add anything to the global `window` object, but that's where AngularJS 1.2 looks for functions when you try to use them as controllers. Is you want to wrap your controllers in modules and still use them in the AngularJS 1.2 style, you'll need tp explicitly attach each one to the `window`, either within each module:

```js
// controller.js
export function Controller($scope){
  // do stuff
}
window.Controller = Controller
```

or in a dedicated script:

```js
import { Controller1 } from './controller1.js'
import { Controller2 } from './controller2.js'
import { Controller3 } from './controller3.js'
// ...

Object.assign(window, {
  Controller1,
  Controller2,
  Controller3,
  // ...
})
```

One thing you may want to consider is moving away from the magically-find-my-controller-on-the-window style and instead use the controller registration style:

```js
angular.module('my-app',[])
  .controller('Controller1', function() {
    // do stuff
  })
```

This should work in modules just like it does in traditional scripts, and it eliminates the need for any manual `window` hacking. You could still name the function and export it if you wanted, though there's probably less need at that point:

```js
export function Controller1() {
  // do stuff
}
angular.module('my-app',[]).controller('Controller1', Controller1)
```